# php if date is older than current date then give error

Tags: php

I am trying to create an php error before submitting the form. 
If input date is older than current date then 
echo Your input date is old
. But there is some problem in my code.. Please help

PHP

```
if (strtotime($_POST['expiry_date']) < time()) {
    $errors[] = 'Your input date is old';
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="expiry_date" >
```

Comment: And the value of `$_POST['expiry_date']`?

Comment: If you want to show the user and error 'before submitting' the post, then do it in Javascript. Doing it in PHP means it has already been posted.

Comment: value of $_POST['expiry_date'] is 12/01/2014

Comment: And what is the problem? Is it always claiming the input is old? Never claiming it's old? What kind of expiry_date do you have? Is it something that strtotime() can convert to a time() value? Finally, time() is GMT, while presumably some specific time zone is being used for strtotime() to convert to GMT. Also watch the assumed time and date format (your example of 12/01/2014 is month/day/year in the US, day/month/year in much of Europe).

Comment: Never claiming it's old ,

Comment: That's because 12/01/2014 is not less than the current timestamp. It's 1/13/14 right now.

Comment: Is that `dd/mm/yyyy`? Seems out of place somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime()` makes this easy to do (assuming DD/MM/YYY format for `$_POST['expiry_date']`. `12/01/2014` is ambiguous as to the format of the date. Is that December 1st? Or January 12th? ):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['expiry_date']);
$now  = new DateTime();
if ($date < $now) {
    $errors[] = 'Your input date is old';
}
```

`DateTime` objects are comparable so you don't have to convert them to timestamps or strings to compare them.

Comment: +1 As it's better than `strtotime()`, and setting format is something that should always be done!

Comment: Sorry its 12 january 2012